# Matching string input text with existing string in MySQL and Java

Tags: java, mysql, regex, database

I am having a table 'questions' with following columns:

```
ID (primary key)
question(Question subject/title)
answer(answer to the question)
```

I will have make it so that the user can input a text where he can pose his question. Now when he finnishes and presses a button i want to fire up an event to get questions avaliable similar to his question so he can pick the correct one.

Now how can I match user's input (question) to existing questions in questions table and get the similar ones out?

I have done this so far: I made a String word variable just for this example, thats supposed to be a whole sentence like "how many times".

```
      Connection conn = null;
      PreparedStatement  st = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      String word= "'%times%'";

       try
       {

           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

           Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"root","root");
           st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM qa WHERE question LIKE " + word);
           rs = st.executeQuery();

           while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt(1));
                System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            }
       }
```

and i get the output:

```
2: how many times should you eat per day
: five times
```

So it's working but as you see but I can only search for similar patterns using one word. This will be hard to do when the user is supposed to input a whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As per your explanation you want to search similar questions from database, But that search you have to do according to certain keywords, then based on those keywords you have to use 'LIKE' or 'REGEX' as per the requirement. For identifying the necessary keywords you have to create your own logical algo.

Answer (score 0):

you would either have to write your own search algorithm, or use an existing one such as http://sphinxsearch.com/ or http://lucene.apache.org/ http://lucene.apache.org/solr/